# Wrong number of items displayed when moving or copying files

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

When copying or moving files in Yosemite, Finder says it is preparing (for example) **400** items, when there is actually only **200** items in the folder.

This has been happening a lot recently, on both my computer and external hard drives.

Once the files have been copied over or moved, it has the same original amount of items in the new folder (**200**).

I am just perplexed as to what these other secret files may be?

Comment: Are you just moving files or are you moving apps too? Or is it sometimes one or both?

Comment: if any of the items are packages [photo library files etc], Finder will calculate the contents too